# Where does $_SESSION get stored?

Tags: php, mysql, session

When logging in from iphone app, I call a php script login function that stores a session of the user id. Does this Id get stored on the server or on the iphone?

```
  $_SESSION['IdUser'] = $result['result'][0]['IdUser'];
```

The reason I'm asking is b/c the session is apparently not being stored when I exit the simulator and start it back up so I believe it's being stored on the server. Would I want the session to be stored on the server if I expect multiple users to be on my app at once or would it be better on the client? How does the server know/get the session id from the client? Thanks.

Also I want my users to stay logged in. Obviously.

Comment: Server. Never on the client.

Comment: 5 seconds reading the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php) would of answered this.

Comment: But how can the server store multiple session id's and how does it know who is hitting the server when a post or function get's called that tries to access $_Session?

Comment: Do you know something about `PHPSESSID`, regarding PHP, `ASP.NET_SessionID`, regarding ASP.NET and `JSESSIONID` regarding Java?

Comment: I know how to create one, as far as using a cookie to act as a token I have no experience. In ASP.NET all this is taken care of already by using their built in methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The PHP Documentation on Sessions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php) is pretty clear about this, but I'll summarize:

1. `$_SESSION` is stored on the server.  It's actually in a temporary file that has the session name (usually).
2. The server identifies the user's session via a cookie

If it's easy for you to have the device send the corresponding session cookie with each request (as would happen with a website) then server storage is fine for you.  Otherwise, you may want to use local storage.  There's no concern about multiple users' sessions overriding each other.

Answer (score 2):

Session data by default is stored on the server.  In linux that is generally in a file in the directory /var/lib/php/, but can be also stored in a db or in memory.

A cookie is stored on the client with sesion id that acts as a token to identify the server side data. In the example of session data in /var/lib/php/ the session id stored in the client cookie maps to a file name in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

In a default configuration of PHP, the session data is stored on the server and the identifier is stored on the client as a cookie.

Whether this cookie persists within the session of your app depends on the code that calls your script; you can easily test this by making a few calls to the same script and see if the session stays "active". Exiting the app may or may not destroy any cookies that you've used, but that's exactly what sessions are, i.e. they're not meant to be persistent.

If you want login persistence, you could store the login credentials on the phone itself (make sure you utilize the key chain) so that you can re-establish a session with the server in case it gets interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

The session, or $_SESSION[] variable is stored on the server.  It is very similar to a Cookie, except that it is stored on the server.

So so sum it up,

$_SESSION[] = (SERVER SIDE)

$_COOKIE[] = (CLIENT SIDE)